# Song greyed out in iTunes, not visible on iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

I deleted all songs from my iPhone, but iTunes claims I have two copies of the same song on the phone. They show up greyed out with a sync icon next to them. Syncing has no effect, and they can't be played or deleted from within iTunes.

[image]

On the iPhone itself, it sees no music. (Usage displays "No Data" next to music).

[image]

iTunes 10.7 and iOS 6.1 on iPhone 5. This has been an issue since I got the song in question via a "Song of the week" promotion on iTunes. (This song, and this song only, has been an issue.)

Comment: Have you tried adding the song back on, syncing, and then see if you can remove it?

Comment: @techturtle - Yes, no effect. iTunes still shows it greyed out.

Comment: @Unsigned - No I'm not. I'm going to try your answer and let you know if it works or not.

Answer (score -1):

It's some kind of glitch in the syncing process (maybe something got corrupted?). I'm not sure but some people have been able to fix it by toggling the 'sync automatically' button and sync their iDevice. Possibly repeat once or twice. If that doesn't work, try duplicating the file or importing it again to iTunes (copy it from iTunes Media if it's there).

Another issue might be that the file of the song is corrupted. Try to identify the file and see if you can play it with any other music player. If not, delete it from there and download, rip or buy the song again.

Comment: I tried redownloading it several times. It plays fine in QuickTime.